# ListView.builder inside FutureBuilder widget returns null even if it's populated?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm new to Flutter and I keep running into the same issue.

```
Future<List<DonationDTO>> getUsersAppointments() async {
  List<DonationDTO> AppointmentRes = [];
  AppointmentRes = (await _apiClient.getDonationsOfUser(widget.user.id, widget.accesstoken));

return AppointmentRes;
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      elevation: .0,
      leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          color: Colors.white),
      title: Text("text"),
    ),
    body:SingleChildScrollView(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<DonationDTO>>(
        future: getUsersAppointments(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
            return new Container(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      if (!snapshot.data[index].hasData || snapshot.data[index].hasError) {
                      return new Container(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else {
                      return Text('${snapshot.data[index].id}');}
                    }));

         }
        }
      ),
     ),
    ),
   );
  }
```

The problem with this widget is that while using the ListView I keep getting a null value error, more specifically when I try to get data from snapshot.data[index].

It also appears that when I display the content of snapshot.data I get this:
[Instance of 'DonationDTO', Instance of 'DonationDTO']

I don't know how to fix this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot.data[index]` points to a list item of `DonationDTO` type, which has no `hasData` and `hasError` properties. In `itemBuilder` it is safe to use `snapshot.data[index]` without checks.

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be the case for this type and any other type as well (tried returning a string, even a list of strings, and the error keeps persisting). Do you know how i can avoid that?

Comment: What is the exact error you get after the changes?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I did not get the point on the spot, but removing the methods you said fixed the issue and using snapshot.data[index] worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the other answer is correct for this case. If you want to solve this not only *this time* but for all future uses, you should declare your types and not use implicit `dynamic` that you end up with if you miss a declaration.

A `FutureBuilder<List<DonationDTO>>` does not receive just any type of `AsyncSnapshot`. It receives a `AsyncSnapshot<List<DonationDTO>>`. And from there on, your compiler got your back. `.data` is no longer of type `dynamic` where you have to guess (in this specific case you guesses wrong, which explains your problem) but of type `List<DonationDTO>` and you *and your compiler* can tell exactly what to do and what would be wrong.